# Java code framework to Spark execution environment

Tags: java, serialization, apache-spark, dataset

I have a Java code framework working which is responsible to validate a set of Objects obtained from another set of files. There a a lot of validation classes which implements an interface **ObjectValidator**

```
public interface ObjectValidator<T extends ObjectRoot> extends Serializable {
    public void validate(T object);
}
```

Then, if I want to create a new validator class, I just have to implement this inteface and introduce the specific validation process code within **onSource** method.

Framework is handling a lot of **ObjectRoots**, which are distributed in several files, then a thread solution was taken, where every thread reads an amount of source from the files and they are passed to the validator, which is shared by all the threads.

Nothing new until here, but problems appear when I try to adapt this framework to Spark execution environment. I mean, instead of use threads, the idea is to use a **Dataset of ObjectRoots**, and then avoid threads and call every validator as:

```
ObjectValidator<ObjectRoot> validator = new SpecificObjectValidator();
Dataset<ObjectRoot> dataset = getDatasetFromParquetFiles();
dataset.toJavaRDD().foreach(object -> validator.validate(object));
```

Framework already contains a lot of validators, and every one of them is using external APIs. I've already done an adaptation of the framework for Spark execution support, but when I execute it, **NotSerializableException** is thrown.

I can serialize all those object belonging to my framework but not all of them provided by APIs, then my question is whether exists any way to avoid serialization of all those external API classes. Should I wrap all of them? or exists any other faster or easier solution?

### Using Kryo

For instance, following exception is thrown:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.commons.configuration.BaseConfiguration
```

And I've started **SparkSession** by using **Kryo** serialization:

```
SparkConf config = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local")
    .setAppName(getClass().getSimpleName())
    .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
    .registerKryoClasses(new Class<?>[] {
        org.apache.commons.configuration.BaseConfiguration.class
    });

SparkContext context = new SparkContext(config);
SparkSession session = new SparkSession(context);
```

But same exception is still thrown! Anyone knows why it is thrown although I'm registering it to Kryo classes?